# Multiplication with a diagonal matrix that can have infinity values

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

I'm thinking how to program the evaluation of the expression $A (B+A)^{-1}$, where $A$ is a diagonal matrix with elements equal or greater than zero, and B is a square symmetric definite positive matrix. The difficulty resides in the fact that the elements in the diagonal matrix $A$ can be infinity. If all the elements in $A$ are infinity, then $A (B+A)^{-1} = I$

A straightforward implementation is easy to do, because a standard Cholesky decomposition can be applied for obtaining that inverse, and if you assign high values such as $10^{10}$ instead of infinity, you get the numerical results you would expect. However, I don't like using this technique, because high values instead of infinity can cause accuracy problems, and it's not a tidy solution at all.

I did it symbolically in Mathematica, using 6x6 matrices to begin with (I foresee using it in matrices of up to 40x40 or so), and found that the result of the expression is always a diagonal matrix (I don't have a proof for that, but Mathematica gave me a diagonal matrix for all posible cases in 6x6).

Would I get the desired solution if I rearrange the rows and columns in $A$ and $B$ so that I solve it only for the $n \times n$ submatrix with non-infinity values in $A$, and then take the rest of the result as a unit matrix?

Or do you foresee another way of implementing it?

Note: You can try this example in Mathematica, in which B is a 6x6 symmetric matrix and with only one non-infinite value in A:

```
b = {{b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16}, {b12, b22, 
   b23, b24, b25, b26}, {b13, b23, b33, b34, b35, 
   b36}, {b14, b24, b34, b44, b45, b46}, {b15, b25, 
   b35, b45, b55, b56}, {b16, b26, b36, b46, b56, 
   b66}}

a = DiagonalMatrix[{v, s, s, s, s, s}]

Limit[a*Inverse[b + a], s -> Infinity, Direction -> 1]
```

And the solution it gives is:

```
{{v/(v + b11), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you even define the inverse of a matrix with infinite entries. For example, $$A=\begin{bmatrix}\infty&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}, A+B =\begin{bmatrix}\infty&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$$ What matrix times $A+B$ is going to give $I$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair You need to wear the mindset of stiffness matrix structural analysis problems, where the recommended approach is to get rid of the rows and columns that represent supports/constraints (ie: zero displacement, or "boundary conditions" in mathematical jargon), but, even if that's the recommended approach, quite a few people keep those rows and columns and just add infinite (say: 10^whatever) to the diagonal, because a support is a spring of infinite stiffness, and yes, it's correct. The problem in my question is not the analysis of a structure, but it's related.

Comment: No. You are trying to communicate to mathematicians here. That means *you* need to wear the mindset of *your* audience instead of demanding that they should just know what you mean without any explanation. If you cannot be bothered to explain what you mean, then there is no point my trying to further engage with you about it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I have edited the question for adding a Mathematica example with 5 infinity values in the diagonal, and only one non-infinity. And yes, the inverse (actually the limit of the inverse when the values are close to infinity) is well defined.

Comment: So - what you are actually doing is introducing a *finite* variable $s$, doing all the calculations, then in the result, letting $s \to \infty$. THAT makes sense. $A+B =\begin{bmatrix}s+2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$, $(A+B)^{-1} =\frac 1{3+2s}\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&2+s\end{bmatrix}$ and  $$A(A+B)^{-1} =\frac 1{3+2s}\begin{bmatrix}2s&-s\\-1&2+s\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}1&-\frac 12\\0&\frac12\end{bmatrix}$$This is something where math can be done.

Comment: I believe your result should be a diagonal matrix. The symbolic result for 6x6 gives me always a diagonal matrix in Mathematica (with the only requirement that B is a symmetric 6x6 matrix, and that A is a diagonal matrix -with arbitrary values in each of the diagonal elements), and I guess it will be the same for matrices of any size. What I don't have is a proof for that, and I don't know why this interesting feature happens.

Comment: I have checked @PaulSinclair's calculations and they seem correct.

Comment: I wouldn't have been surprised had there been a mistake, as I was trying to be quick, and accidently messed up several things (you may have notices that I posted the comment, then deleted it and reposted after I realized I'd messed up on the inverse - too late to fix it by editing.) However I suspect your diagonal matrices were due to other regularities in your matrices not required here. Possibly coming from something in the source of your data, or possibly due to your choosing too simple of examples.

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct. I need to think more about this. Thanks for your help!